# URL rewrite for JSF

Tags: jsf, prettyfaces

I'm using JSF, Jboss. I used urlrewrite filter and i don't know why:
when i type `localhost:8080/myweb/user/myname` will be forwarded to `localhost:8080/myweb/user.xhtml?u=myname`. it makes me don't like urlrewritefilter.
After that, i try using prettyfaces. Maybe, it is good for others, not me. i can't find out good tutorials except the documentation. ajax error after adding prettyfaces into my project. And some codes in pretty-config.xml

```
    <url-mapping id="ideas"> 
        <pattern value="/article/#{g}" />
        <view-id value="/ideas/article.xhtml" />
    </url-mapping> -->
```

And a form in jsf page will redirect this page with param

```
public String addUserToGroup() {
        ...
        return "/ideas/article.xhtml?g=" + g + "&faces-redirect=true";
    }
```

can't run.
Can you give me some advices about what library i should use to rewrite URL now. Or how to fix errors of prettyfaces. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is your configuration commented out? I noticed the '`-->`' in your code snippit.

```
<url-mapping id="ideas"> 
    <pattern value="/article/#{g}" />
    <view-id value="/ideas/article.xhtml" />
</url-mapping> -->
```